# How to get cart's items for a specific user using laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get cart's items for specific user when user is logout so cart's items should be remove from shopping cart how to get please help me thanks ?

**controller**

```
        public function addCart(Request $request)
        {
        $product = Product::findOrFail($request->id);

        $cartItem = Cart::add([
       'id' => $product->id,
       'name' => $product->product_name,
       'brand'=>$product->product_brand,
       'image'=>$product->product_image,
       'qty' => $request->qty,
       'price' => $product->product_price,
        ]);

        Cart::associate($cartItem->rowId, 'App\Product');

       return redirect()->route('cart.index');
      }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What package are you using for the Cart? Are you using `loudemans/shoppingcart`?

Answer (score 1):

Your Model is missing a relation to an User - the way you solved this problem for now would only work if you only have one user on your website.

Which means:
extend you migration of `Cart` with user_id, define the relation in your model.

After that you can Listen to the `Logout` Event: https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Auth/Events/Logout.html handle the logic for the "removal"

You can just do a: Cart::whereUserId($event->userId)->get() and there you got all cart items.

More information to events: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/events